# Avoiding MemoryError when iterating over generator

Tags: python, loops, generator

I have a big file that directly reading to memory is raising `MemoryError`. I overcome that by reading it to the generator

```
def rea():
    with open('D:\\random.forge', 'rb') as f:
        yield f.read()
```

When I am want to iterate over the created generator from `rea()` using `for loop` I always have `MemoryError`. I came up to delete iterated value using `del` keyword, but it seems that when you iterate over the generator with `for loop` it saves the whole generator into memory. Can I somehow iterate over the generator in such a specific situation? The file's size is a few GBs.

Comment: And what do you want to do with that content ?

Answer (score 1):

The method `.read()` reads the **whole** file, so that loads it in memory.

---

You may read it progressively.

1. For a text file, you can read by line :

   ```
   def read():
       with open('D:\\random.forge', 'r') as f:
           return f

   for line in read():
       print(line)
   ```
2. For a binary file, you can read by batch of bytes:

   ```
   def read():
       CHUNKSIZE = 1024 # for example
       with open('D:\\random.forge', 'rb') as f:
           bytes_read = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
           while bytes_read:
               yield bytes_read
               bytes_read = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)

   for bytes_batch in read():
       do_stuff(bytes_batch)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `f.read()` loads the whole file into memory upon the first iteration over the generator you have created.

Try yielding lines, instead of the whole content:

```
def rea():
    with open('D:\\random.forge', 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Answer (score -1):

`f.read()` can take a parameter for chunk size, which is the size of the file you want to read in one iteration. For example if you want to read 1 kb at a time, you can set chunk size to 1024.

```
def rea(chunk_size=1024):
    with open('D:\\random.forge', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read(chunk_size)
        yield data
```